# Filter trash from Byte[]

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, filter, arrays

I want to filter out a lot of trash from my Byte[]. but I don't know how I should do it.

When I convert the Byte[] to a string, the output is the following:

```
[00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][05][00][00][00][02][02]PÑ[0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][02][00][00][00][02][03][15][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][02][00][00][00][02][02][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][04][00][00][00][02]PÑ[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][04][00][00][00][02][02]PÑ[0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][02][00][00][00][02][03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][06][00][00][00][02][02]PÑ[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][01][00][00][00][02][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][05][00][00][00][02][02]PÑ[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][06][00][00][00][02][02]PÑ[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][01][00][00][00][02][15][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][02][00][00][00][02][02][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00]([00][00][00][02]PB000A07B;1359120102;NL1200000002 ;w4[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][06][00][00][00][02][02]PB01[0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00]$[00][00][00][02]4EC8F;1359300102;NL1200000001 ;Ey³[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][08][00][00][00][02][02]PCD325[0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00]"[00][00][00][02]973;1325301402;NL1200000004 ;AOl[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][03][00][00][00][02][02]P[0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][03][00][00][00][02]Ñ[03][0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][03][00][00][00][02][02]P[0B][00][01][00][00][00]ÿÿÿÿ[01][00][00][00][00][00][00][00][0F][01][00][00][00][03][00][00][00][02]Ñ[03][0B]
```

That is you can see a lot, I want to filter out the following: `[00]`, `[0F]`, `ÿÿÿÿ` and `[01]`.

How do I filter this string that way? And if possible, how do I filter the `Byte[]` direct without converting to string first? Because that would help me a lot if there is a way to filter the `byte[]` direct from the following items: `[00]`, `[0F]`, `ÿÿÿÿ` and `[01]`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does your byte[] contain? What do you want your string to show?

Comment: The best way to filter out the trash is to avoid adding trash in the first place. If you have control over the producing side, consider fixing it, rather than fixing the receiver.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: byte[] contains bytes not chars, ÿ can be 1 byte or more bytes depending on character encoding.

Comment: Thanks, will try to get access to the source filling the Byte Array, problem is that it is code that I didn't create, So I will need to ask permission to change that side of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I filter this string that way?

You can use this regex:

```
string filteredStr = Regex.Replace(strWithTrash, @"\[00\]|\[01\]|\[0F\]|(ÿÿÿÿ)", "");
// now, you can convert your filtered string back to a byte array
```

> And if possible, how do I filter the Byte[] direct without converting to string first?

For that, you could use loops, and looking at the char code of `[`, `0`, `1`, `F`, `]` and `ÿ`, but it is a **lot** easier to just convert it to a string and remove the trash.